# Migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 problem(s)

Tags: upgrade

We were using our SharePoint Site without problems on SP 2010 server. Recently, it was demanded to migrate to SP 2013 server.

I had done all the necessaries, but the problem which persists, is that we are using a custom template which was developed by an external client. In this template, there is a web part.
After creating the site collection from this template, I cannot open the site, an error occurred.

In case when I have to re-develop this web part or this template (i don't know), what is the best to do that, or what steps should I begin with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you remove the webpart from the site collection?

Comment: Can you post the actual error from the ULS logs? The first screen seems to indicate that there is a problem with the templates used by the sites, but it doesn't really provide much more detail.

Comment: the first screen is generated when i try to upgrade web site to SP 2013 by clicking on the top bar of the screen (Experience all that SharePoint 15 has to offer ...)

Comment: Yes i can remove the web part, and like that i have a working web site

Comment: yes, custom webparts and custom features will not be brought over to the destination sharepoint version. You will need to redeploy your webpart in the new environment.